# How to multiply all values by a one multiplier from Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 columns with source values for multiplying. I need to multiply each value by multiplier and set result to the next 3 columns accordance with sources.
I made a script for this:

```js
function getDefaultPor() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let rg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3),
      mp = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue(),
      targetRange = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3),
      arrVals = rg.getValues();
  targetRange.setValues(arrVals.map(row => row.map(col => col / mp)))
};
```

I works...but in cases when cells of source values are empty (`""`) my function returns according results as `0`. I need to keep it empty as `""`.

How can I do this?

Updated with logs:

```js
function getDefaultPor() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let rg = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3),
      mp = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue(),
      targetRange = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3),
      arrVals = rg.getValues();
  targetRange.setValues(arrVals.map(row => row.map(col => !isNaN(col) ? col / mp : col)));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arrVals)) // log: [[1,2,3],["","",""],[2,8,6],[4,5,7],[6,2,8],[8,8,9],[10,6,10],["","",""],[4,5,7],[6,2,8]]
  let result = targetRange.getValues();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) //log: [[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0,0,0],[0.2,0.8,0.6],[0.4,0.5,0.7],[0.6,0.2,0.8],[0.8,0.8,0.9],[1,0.6,1],[0,0,0],[0.4,0.5,0.7],[0.6,0.2,0.8]]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the values of columns "A", "B" and "C" divided by `mp` to the columns "D", "E" and "F".
- When the values of columns "A", "B" and "C" are the empty, you want to keep the empty at the columns "D", "E" and "F".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
targetRange.setValues(arrVals.map(row => row.map(col => col / mp)))
```

#### To:

```
targetRange.setValues(arrVals.map(row => row.map(col => col != "" ? col / mp : col)));
```

#### Note:

- In this case, when the value is the string, the string value is put. When the value is the number, the value is divided by `mp`.
- Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in your case, you might be able to select `isNaN` and `Number.isNaN`.

#### References:

- [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)
- [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)